# Azure functions with complex c# code

Tags: azure, stream, azure-functions

I have complex code in c# with multiple classes(and classes have different functions) and i want to implement it as azure function. The problem is that the architecture is as follows: stream data is coming to function as input and after complex calculation within the class functions, I need to return calculated values as stream again. To be returned values are inside class functions and I am having trouble to find a way to return these to "run" function. Is there any easy way to do it?
Structure is like this

```
public static void Run(string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
 // gets data from service bus per second
 call function 1
}

public class Class1
{
function1(){
 call function2
 }
}

public class Class2
{
function2()
output interested is in here and program creates an output after 30 31 seconds and continues to creates about every 20 second
)}
```

Many thanks

Comment: many thanks for your answer. I have updated question accordingly

Comment: `function2` - is it somewhat like a loop running and emitting events every 20 seconds? Or does it have a timer of 20 seconds? So for each incoming message you create a long-running process? When does it stop?

Comment: many thanks for help. there is not loop running for function2, it stops when there is no message coming from service bus. So functions gets inputs messages from service bus, aggregates and calculates some value and pass these to function2. Function2 again do more calculations and creates output to be sent other componets of azure. Does it makes sense

Comment: So does function2 return a result message per each incoming message, which should be sent to the output queue?

Comment: No, function2 returns calculated values from multiple coming messages and   these calculated values should be sent to output queue

Comment: You should take a look at Durable Functions announced recently - https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/articles/overview.html. This may be something that you can use.

Comment: it looks like perfect match of what I need. It adresses the problems that Mikhail has stated. Thanks @GauravMantri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but based on your comments I understood that your processing logic and calculation results depend on multiple incoming messages.

Azure Function (`Run` method) will be called once per each Service Bus message in your queue. That means that you need to persist some state, e.g. the previous messages, across Function calls.

Azure Functions themselves don't provide any reliable in-process state storage, so you need to make use of external storage (e.g. SQL Database, Cosmos DB, Table Storage etc).

Your function flow would look something like this:

1. `Run` is called for an incoming Service Bus message.
2. You load the previous state of the function from external storage.
3. You instantiate Class1/Class2/etc hierachy.
4. You pass the incoming message AND your state to Class1/Class2.
5. Your logic produces an output message, new state, or both.
6. You persist the state back to the storage.
7. You return the output message to the output binding.

In case you don't want any external state, Azure Functions might not be the right service for you. E.g. you may have a Web Job, which constantly runs and keeps a series of messages in memory.

Edit: As @Gaurav suggested, you should take a look at 
[Durable Functions](https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/articles/), but they are still at early preview stage.

Comment: Hello Mikhail, I am already storing states and calculations inside classes so i guess i am at completely wrong path. I thought that as we do in c#, we can  store the state of class object in azure functions as well. Is is totally wrong?

Comment: @emkay The problem is that subsequent calls of Functions are not guaranteed to be in the same process or even machine (remember dynamic scaling). So any in-memory state may preserve sometimes, but you can't rely on that.

Comment: So in this case, do you recommend web jobs ? assuming that  durable functions are in early stage.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [`Azure Durable Functions`](https://azure.github.io/azure-functions-durable-extension/articles/overview.html) announced recently. Unfortunately I have only read about it and not used it, hence I will not be able to propose how exactly it will solve your problem.

One neat thing I liked about this is that unlike your regular Functions, they are `stateful` in nature which lets you persist the local state.

Another thing I liked about this is that it is intended for long running tasks which is something you're after.

Looking at your question, I believe `Function Chaining` pattern is something that could be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Azure Functions are not designed for complex processing. Instead you can consider worker roles for this or a microservice if your solution is already on Service Fabric.

Comment: Well, that's a bold statement. Really depends on what kind of "complex" we talk about. I see no issues with "multiple classes" kind of complex in Function Apps.